# Ignore a Key with JSON encode

Tags: flutter, dart, jsonserializer

How can I ignore a key when using `json.encode`?

Something like this:

```
final map = json.decode(json.encode(routine), reviver: (key, value) {
      if (key == "id") {
        return null;
      }
      return value;
    });
```

But this way my map has a key `id` with value `null`. I want my map to not have the id key.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the key.

```
routine.remove("id");
final map = json.decode(json.encode(routine));
```